# Is a Weil divisor Cartier after some multiple?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a variety, a Weil divisor $D$, can we always add multiplicity such that $mD$ is Cartier? If it is not true, is there a counterexample, and what kind of singularities are allowed for this to be true ?

Comment: The varieties with this property are called $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest example is a cone over an elliptic curve: Take a ruling over a non-torsion point in group law of the curve, and no multiple is Cartier (the class group of the local ring at the vertex is the Picard group of the curve mod the hyperplane class). In the case of surfaces, the class of rational double point singularities give examples of cases for which it is true that every Weil divisor is $\mathbb Q$-Cartier, simply because the class groups are finite.